# Getting Swedish characters from a textbox control

Tags: asp.net, encoding, textbox

I'm getting my text from a textbox from code-behind using control.Text()
but I'm not getting the proper characters, I want "ÅÄÖ". Must be some problem with the text encoding but I've already checked my encoding settings in VS. Someone??

Comment: What characters are you getting instead of ÅÄÖ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"  />
```

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893663

Answer (score 0):

The letters looks swedish - hence I have made the following to match swedish letters. If it's another language change the culture.

in your web.config set the following

```
<configuration>
      <system.web>
         <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="sv-SE" uiCulture="en-US" />
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```